# Persian Datepicker in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, datetime, datepicker, calendar

I try use Bootstrap persian datepicker but it briken my html template so
How make persian(Jalali) datepicker for a input in Asp.Net core, Without Bootstrap.

Comment: Could you pls let me know the difference between persian(Jalali) datepicker and normal datapicker? By the way, I want to double confirm with you that if we can try to remove the classes/style for the datapicker to make it not influence your template?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.